# How to send data from S3 to vertica using IAM ROLE?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, vertica

I have a requirement of moving data from aws s3 to vertica using aws roles.

I have created a table with admin user and created a policy with s3 full access , attached it to our vertica role and that in turn is attached vertica instances running on AWS.

VERTICA VERSION

Vertica Analytic Database v8.1.1-3

COMMAND:

COPY scratch.my_test SOURCE S3(url='https://s3.amazonaws.com/xxxx-xx/test.csv');

My Table:

Has only one column , name which is varchar(64)

My test.csv

name --> column

test --> this is my  value

ERROR:

SQL Error [6085] [VP001]: [Vertica]VJDBC ERROR: Unexpected exception calling process() User Function in UDSource
  [Vertica]VJDBC ERROR: Unexpected exception calling process() User Function in UDSource
    com.vertica.util.ServerException: [Vertica]VJDBC ERROR: Unexpected exception calling process() User Function in UDSource

POLICY:

I also test with this policy , i got the same error.

{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::xxx-xx",
                "arn:aws:s3:::xxx-xx/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}

Someone please point where i am wrong, and also some suggestions.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know Vertica at all but the problem is likely to be that you have specified the URL of the S3 object incorrectly. You have asked Vertica to load from `https://s3.amazonaws.com/xxxx-xx/test.csv` which is an HTTP URL. There is no authentication in this request. It's just as if you hit the URL from a browser, and you would be denied access.

I believe that you should supply the URL as `s3://xxxx-xx/test.csv`.

I'm assuming that your IAM policy is correct and indicates `arn:aws:s3:::xxxx-xx` and `arn:aws:s3:::xxxx-xx/*` (note the trailing asterisk on the latter so that it applies to all objects under the xxxx-xx bucket).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for taking time to check my issue, 
When i added the url you suggested , i got the following error

```
SQL Error [6783] [VP001]: [Vertica][VJDBC](6783) ERROR: Filesystem does not support glob s3://xxx-xx/test.csv
  [Vertica][VJDBC](6783) ERROR: Filesystem does not support glob s3://xxx-xx/test.csv
    com.vertica.util.ServerException: [Vertica][VJDBC](6783) ERROR: Filesystem does not support glob s3://xxx-xx/test.csv
```

This helped me to find that, I should mount my s3 bucket into vertica

https://github.com/vertica/aws-lambda-vertica-loader#set-up-s3-bucket-mounts ( steps are here)

Discussion ( https://forum.vertica.com/discussion/205657/load-data-from-amazon-s3-bucket-to-vertica )